# Trying to find and replace string by javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging

I was trying to find and replace string by JavaScript but my routine is not working. I guess there is some mistake. Please guide me what to fix in js routine. Here is my script.

```
function ReplaceChars(srcString)
{
    var IgnoreChars = ['<', '>',':', '/', '?', '#', '[', ']', '@', '!', '$', '&', '(', ')', '*', '', '+', ',', ';', '=', ']', ';'];
    for (i = 0; i < srcString.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < IgnoreChars.length; j++) {
            if (srcString.charAt(i) == IgnoreChars.charAt(j))
            {
                srcString=srcString.replace(srcString.charAt(i), '');
            }
        }
    }
    return srcString;
}

var str = '<name>';
alert(ReplaceChars(str));
```

Comment: Define 'not working'

Comment: not clear....what u trying to say??

Comment: you have an empty string in the list of ignored characters. Is that expected? (between `*` and `+`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. 
IgnoreChars is an array - not a String - so it doesn't have a charAt function;
change this line:

```
 if (srcString.charAt(i) == IgnoreChars.charAt(j))
```

to

```
 if (srcString.charAt(i) == IgnoreChars[j])
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q0ztudLd/

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use RegEx:

```
var str = "<name>";
var reg = /[<>:\/?#\[\]@!]/g
//add more characters to the RegEx

var newStr = str.replace(reg, "");
console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try this:

```
IgnoreChars.charAt(j)
```

`charAt` is a string function not an array function.

With `IgnoreChars[j]` it will work.